# Process finished with exit code 0 at compile time in pytest API Testing

Tags: python, pytest, web-api-testing

Trying to fetch data from created fixture but at Compile time getting error :Process finished with exit code 0
So please help me to remove that error and make my code running and as an output fixture setup1 has to be run

```
def setup1():

    headers = {
        'url' : "http://api.staging.customerlobby.com/v2/companies.json",
        'Authorization': "token=\"ywlGaT0X44WGEps98WDN8xyFMmJgfGTehKxT5heiq_A7yqa_xwM9z6s2ouB1R7LprEYaTtXoILzx713kYhvoOxQrPLsRuvEAhnHfpc0sRonNXRYJgD91P8c2_mJJJ58MYs2TiMCEXlByG2ODRrb9e5OA35l74HXAegMabFJE7GnLX_4ZCxD2EygFP8LKqamdfao66QXAmXW60nwWYOF7g3bPdQNH3eK2siY9yODd_pFJ2IpLxBiadEFvAWZj5Y\"",
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
        'Postman-Token': "6546678f-d9c2-434f-8192-2695ce9641f1"
    }

    def test_api_get(setup1):
        # A get request (json example):
        response_data = None
        try:
            response_data = requests.get(setup1['url'], headers= setup1['Authorization'])
           # response = urllib.urlopen(self.myurl)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        data = response_data.json()
        print("Response Data="+str(data))
        print(response_data.status_code)
        assert 200 == response_data.status_code
```

Comment: "exit code 0" is success. You *want* a process to exit with that status.

Comment: BTW, your `setup1` function *defines* a `test_api_get` function, but that function is never called. Do you expect something to call it? (And how do you expect the `setup1` name to be bound to your `headers` dict? If that doesn't happen, how do you expect `setup1['url']` or `setup1['Authorization']` to make any sense?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah, i want to call that function but don't know how to do it

Comment: Why are you putting your function inside another function in the first place? Easiest way to make your function callable is just to define it in module scope rather than nesting it pointlessly.